# Fastest possible object remapping for nested structure

Tags: javascript, performance, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

Assume we have two different structures from two different APIs. Each has a different schema.

We have this as a return from API #1

```
[
    {
        Id: "test1",
        Title: "label 1",
        Children: [
            {
                Id: "test2",
                Title: "label 2",
                Children: [
                    {
                        Id: "test3",
                        Title: "label 3"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to convert it to the following scheme:

```
[
    {
        value: "test1",
        label: "label 1",
        children: [
            {
                value: "test2",
                label: "label 2",
                children: [
                    {
                        value: "test3",
                        label: "label 3"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

So far I have come up with this method:

```
const transformItem = ({ Id, Title, Children }) => ({
  value: Id,
  label: Title,
  children: Children ? transformData(Children) : null
});

const transformData = arr => arr.map(item => transformItem(item));

// Process data
const DataForApi2 = transformData(DataFromApi1);
```

From the limited benchmarking I performed and from what I can tell, in V8 (which is 95+% of our userbase) this looks fast enough as I'm not mutating any data structure (ergo hot objects are intact and retain performance) and using everything under a scope so I don't waste memory. Seems to be of linear complexity and not too bad if only performed once per client loading the app (only the first time after login).

Comment: The community seems to prefer that questions like this be asked over at https://codereview.stackexchange.com, but of course, read their help first to make sure you present it correctly for that site's rules.

Comment: A long shot, but because your structure is mostly the same and only the keys are changing, perhaps stringifying the objects and doing a string global find-replace it may be faster. Not sure though.

Comment: FWIW, your analysis seems good to me. **If** the original data is ephemeral **and** the API ignores properties it doesn't use, you could just modify the existing objects, either leaving the old props in place or writing `undefined` to them. V8 is very fast at that. But both those preconditions would have to be true.

Comment: @Zenkylo - With the values being strings, you'd have to guard against property names in strings, which gets messy and hard to maintain **fast**. :-) (I'm also fairly sure making a round-trip through JSON would be slower than what the OP has, since it still involves creating new objects, but with a lot more branching.)

Comment: `const transformData = arr => arr.map(transformItem);`

Comment: @Thomas excellent point, I've rewritten it a couple times and missed this one :)

Answer (score 0):

In terms of runtime you're right this is probably the fastest we can get with `O(n)`.

You could improve your space complexity by converting your solution from recursive to iterative. It [saves space on the callstack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15684914/4842949) which helps in extreme cases where trees go extremely deep.